# How to make one thread wait for another thread several times in expected order

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am a novice in the field of C++ multithread programming. I want to read block data from my disk and do some computation based on these data. In order to simplify the code, I write the following demo to test my idea.

The read data function is as the following.

```
void read_value(std::vector<int> &data)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        cv_m.lock();
        std::cout << "read data iteration is " << j << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            data.at(i) = i * j;
        is_print = true;
        cv_m.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}
```

In this function, I want to read data 4 times and after each read, I want to call another function called `print_value` to output the data. The `print_value` function is here.

```
void print_value(const std::vector<int> &data)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        std::cout << "waiting for output data" << std::endl;
        cv.wait(lk, []{return is_print;});
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
            std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
        is_print = false;
    }
}
```

Although I set the `print_value` function to wait 4 times, there is another problem. The `read_value` function will not wait for the `print_value` function and it will just read data 4 times. The output result is as the following.

```
read data iteration is 1
read data iteration is 2
read data iteration is 3
read data iteration is 4
waiting for output data
0
4
8
12
16
waiting for output data
Program ended with exit code: 9
```

I know it is very dangerous for two threads to wait for each other. It seems that the conditional variable can only be used when one thread waits for another instead of my case. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: If one function has to wait for another, your problem is serial in nature and multi-threading wont yield performance improvements as you cant execute them in parralel

Comment: @Tom  Well, I mean I want to read data from disk and put those data on GPU to do some computation. During the computation process, I can also read data from disk again and put data on GPU immediately after the former computation.

Comment: Look up *producer-consumer*.

Comment: @tom between 100% serial and 100%  multi-threading there are a lot of cases. When for instance you compile a project producing a lot of binaries and libs you can compile files in parallel but you have to wait all the necessary binaries are made to make the libs, and for the final link to wait until all the needed binaries and libs are made.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you, I will check it.

Comment: @bruno I agree with you. I just want to create something like a buffer for my data at the dist.

Comment: @n.m. I believe that there is a big difference between the producer-consumer and my case. In my case, the producer has to wait for the signal from the consumer.

Comment: @Sean Tell me if I understood your problem correctly, your producer should wait to make sure it'll free-up `data`? Then you should do double-buffering. Otherwise, you'll have serial order of execution and multithreading won't have any sense.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko You are right. After my producer gives the data to the consumer, the consumer should do something with that data. At the same time, my producer can read next batch data from the disk. However, at this point , my producer has to wait for the consumer finishing its job. I am not sure if I explain clearly.

Comment: @Sean Then you should use double buffering

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but instead of explicitly calling `lock()` and `unlock()` on the mutex, the code should use `std::lock_guard`. That way it's exception-safe. As written, if the call to `data.at(i)` throws an exception the mutex stays locked and it's very hard to sort out how to recover.

Comment: The producer has to wait for a signal from the consumer in all cases except when it magically possesses a queue of infinite capacity. Your queue has capacity of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solve this problem by using state transition. I set a global variable state. When the state is equal to one, the thread one starts to reading data and the thread two sleeps until the state is changed to two. In such cases, although the CPU takes up more resource, I can manage my program successfully.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have `read_value` wait on the condition variable as well. See [the example code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) of `std::condition_variable`, adapted to your loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool read_ready = false;
bool print_ready = false;

void read_value(std::vector<int> &data)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        // Wait until print_value is done with the previous data
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []{return read_ready;});

        std::cout << "read data iteration is " << j << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            data.at(i) = i * j;
        print_ready = true;
        read_ready = false;
        lk.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
    }
}

void print_value(const std::vector<int> &data)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        read_ready = true;
        lk.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
        lk.lock();

        std::cout << "waiting for output data" << std::endl;
        cv.wait(lk, []{return print_ready;});
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
            std::cout << data[i] << std::endl;
        print_ready = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation first. I still have a few questions about your code. First of all, what about the first iteration? At the first iteration, both of these functions are waiting for wake up. Do we need to call cv.notify_one() in the main thread? Besides, after the print_value calls cv.notify_one(), the read_value function will read next batch data from disk and then call cv.notify_one(). However, what if the read_value function calls cv.notify_one() before print_value finishes its job?

Comment: @Sean `print_value` notifies (with `read_ready`) before it waits, and `read_value` waits before it notifies. Remember that a mutex is (temporarily) unlocked while it is involved in a cv `wait`

Comment: Well, do you have a test about your code? It seems that there is a problem with it. Just like what I said above.  The read_value will not wait for the signal from print_value and it just runs until the last iteration. By the way, the std::lock_guard is a template class without the method unlock(). Could you please check it? Thank you!